# Python search list of objects that contain objects, partial matches

Tags: python, search, full-text-search, pymssql

I'm trying to build a simple search engine for a small website. My initial thought is to avoid using larger packages such as Solr, Haystack, etc. because of the simplistic nature of my search needs.

My hope is that with some guidance I can make my code more pythonic, efficient, and most importantly function properly.

Intended functionality: return product results based on full or partial matches of item_number, product name, or category name (currently no implementation of category matching)

Some code:

```
import pymssql
import utils #My utilities  

class Product(object):  
   def __init__(self, item_number, name, description, category, msds):
        self.item_number = str(item_number).strip()
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.category = category
        self.msds = str(msds).strip()

class Category(object):  
    def __init__(self, name, categories):
        self.name = name
        self.categories = categories
        self.slug = utils.slugify(name)
        self.products = []

categories = (
    Category('Food', ('123', '12A')),
    Category('Tables', ('354', '35A', '310', '31G')),
    Category('Chemicals', ('845', '85A', '404', '325'))
)

products = []

conn = pymssql.connect(...)
curr = conn.cursor()

for Category in categories:
    for c in Category.categories:
        curr.execute('SELECT item_number, name, CAST(description as text), category, msds from tblProducts WHERE category=%s', c)
        for row in curr:
            product = Product(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4])
            products.append(product)
            Category.products.append(product)

conn.close()

def product_search(*params):
    results = []
    for product in products:
        for param in params:
            name = str(product.name)
            if (name.find(param.capitalize())) != -1:
                results.append(product)
            item_number = str(product.item_number)
            if (item.number.find(param.upper())) != -1:
                results.append(product)
    print results

product_search('something')
```

MS SQL database with tables and fields I cannot change.
At most I will pull in about 200 products.

Some things that jump out at me.  Nested for loops.  Two different if statements in the product search which could result in duplicate products being added to the results.

My thought was that if I had the products in memory (the products will rarely change) I could cache them, reducing database dependence and possibly providing an efficient search.

...posting for now... will come back and add more thoughts

Edit:
The reason I have a Category object holding a list of Products is that I want to show html pages of Products organized by Category.  Also, the actual category numbers may change in the future and holding a tuple seemed like simple painless solution.  That and I have read-only access to the database.

The reason for a separate list of products was somewhat of a cheat.  I have a page that shows all products with the ability to view MSDS (safety sheets).  Also it provided one less level to traverse while searching.

Edit 2:

```
def product_search(*params):
    results = []
    lowerParams = [ param.lower() for param in params ]

    for product in products:
        item_number = (str(product.item_number)).lower()
        name = (str(product.name)).lower()
        for param in lowerParams:
           if param in item_number or param in name:
               results.append(product)
    print results
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepare all variables outside of the loops and use `in` instead of `.find` if you don't need the position of the substring:

```
def product_search(*params):
    results = []
    upperParams = [ param.upper() for param in params ]

    for product in products:
        name = str(product.name).upper()
        item_number = str(product.item_number).upper()
        for upperParam in upperParams:
            if upperParam in name or upperParam in item_number:
                results.append(product)
    print results
```

Comment: The product names are capitalized but the item_number is always all caps and possibly contains numbers.  For example item_number = 147DECAF.  So I *think* I need to distinguish between name and item_number.

Comment: You dont't have to `str()` the `"147DECAF"` - it looks like a string already.

Comment: If someone searches for 147, won't that be an integer?  There could be multiple item_numbers containing 147.  147DECAF, 147CAF, 147BLAH, etc.

Comment: No. All user input is considered a string and will not be converted automaticly. It's also very unpythonesque to do type checking/converting, unless necessary.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I did not know that.  What about the issue with matching input with item_numbers?  For example:  'Decaf' needs to match '147DECAF' Can I do a case-insensitive comparison?  Case insensitive searching would solve both product name and product item_number scenarios.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this example.  You are creating a list called upperParams, but then are not actually using it anywhere.

Comment: @user593877 - thanks for the upperParams, I have now fixed it all.

Comment: I ended up converting everything to lower to do the comparison.  Not sure how expensive the operation is, but the results are returned quickly.  I'll benchmark it.

Answer (score 0):

If both the name and number matches the search parameters, the product will appear twice on the result list.

Since the products count is a small number, I recommend constructing a `SELECT` query like:

```
def search(*args):
    import operator
    cats = reduce(operator.add, [list(c.categories) for c in categories], [])

    query = "SELECT * FROM tblProducts WHERE category IN (" + ','.join('?' * len(cats)) + ") name LIKE '%?%' or CAST(item_number AS TEXT) LIKE '%?%' ..."
    curr.execute(query, cats + list(args)) # Not actual code
    return list(curr)
```

Comment: Well, the actual table (tblProducts) contains thousands of records.  This is why I was trying to query my existing objects instead of doing what would be a very time consuming query.

Comment: Then your `products` list will also contain thousands of records in memory. The best thing you can do is to actually measure how much time a query like this takes.

Comment: Why would it contain thousands of records?  In my SQL query I'm only pulling products from the table that match my defined categories.

Comment: I will try this out, but I'm a bit lost with what I need to fill in for ... and the #Not actual code.  This might take me a minute.

Comment: I have no control over indexing of the database.  The first query to find ~200 products from a table of thousands based on specific categories is rather time consuming.  I was hoping to avoid querying twice.